# Can the Xbox 360 Kinect work on Windows 8 in place of Kinect for Windows

Tags: windows-8, xbox360, kinect

Is it possible to use a Xbox 360 Kinect with Windows 8 in place of a [Kinect for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/)?

Note that this would be used in a Home Theater PC environment, and not at a normal desktop set up, so range issues aside will it work when connected to a PC or will it just not be recognized.

Answer (score 2):

The [Kinect FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/news/faq.aspx) from Microsoft indicates that there are hardware and software differences that make Kinect for Windows preferred for computer use. I have developed using older versions of the Kinect SDK and the Kinect for Xbox.

Thus, the Kinect for Xbox is not suitable for use in controlling Windows 8 in place of Kinect for Windows.

Comment: So does that mean yes it should work when connected to a PC, but not as well as the PC version?

Comment: Not trying to use the SDK, to develop a Kinect enabled PC app, just trying to use a "Xbox Kinect" to control a Windows 8 PC.

Comment: I have no way to test this, but from the looks of that FAQ, I would say the answer is no. It looks like the APIs for computer control are not available for the Xbox Kinect.

Answer (score 1):

It does work. I'm using an up to date version of the Kinect SDK, using the Kinect that came with my Xbox and the adaptor for connecting it to a regular USB port.

I can't use near mode but I am working on a way to fix this without having to buy a third Kinect for when I'm not using my two I already possess for 3D motion capture.

Comment: i forgotto mention i also am not ableto use near mode but i am working on a way to fix this without having to buy a 3rd kinect for when im not using my 2 i already possess for 3d motion capture

Comment: Welcome to Super User, Lyky. Please spend a little time using a spell checker and properly capitalizing "I" instead of "i" in your posts. That'll make them easier to read for others. Also, you can [edit] your posts anytime to add information.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the Kinect SDK does not support the XBOX 360 Kinect.  While one could use the beta version of the SDK if you could find it, you would be limited the license that came with it, which means you would be unlikely to sell your program.

**You are better of using the Kinect supported by the release drivers because of the performance increase.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about windows 8, but I've managed to get an xbox kinect working with windows 7. I used FAAST http://projects.ict.usc.edu/mxr/faast/ to set up keyboard shortcuts. It worked either through the kinect for windows drivers or ones from OpenNI - hopefully at least one of those routes will work through windows 8.